# How can I trigger the click event of another element in ng-click using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to trigger the click event of the `<input type="file">` element from the `button`.

```
<input id="upload"
    type="file"
    ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"
    style="display: none;">

<button type="button"
    ng-click="angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');">Upload</button>
```

It's common practice to hide the uglified beast known as `<input type=file>` and trigger it's click event by some other means.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If your input and button are siblings (and they are in your case OP):

```
<input id="upload"
    type="file"
    ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"
    style="display: none;">

<button type="button" uploadfile>Upload</button>
```

Use a directive to bind the click of your button to the file input like so:

```
app.directive('uploadfile', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element) {

        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            angular.element(e.target).siblings('#upload').trigger('click');
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: Great directive - it becomes a lot more reusable if you pass in the sibling id in a scope parameters `scope: { siblingId: '=' }` the use the directive like `<button uploadfile sibling-id="upload">Upload</button>`

Comment: Works perfectly--anyone care to explain why triggering a click from a directive like above works, while doing the same from a controller causes an "$apply is already in progress" error?

Comment: @slashp you may need to wrap your call in a `$timeout` so you make sure it runs within an `$apply` cycle

Comment: this works for me using angularjs1.4.5 and take note to include jquery to use .siblings(), but I still have a problem. I have a fab md-button with icon inside. It works only if  I click within the md-button but outside the icon, so I ended up tweaking the directive

Comment: You may want to do this way: angular.element(document.querySelector('#myId')).triggerHandler('click');

Answer (score 15):

So it was a simple fix. Just had to move the `ng-click` to a scope click handler:

```
<input id="upload"
    type="file"
    ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"
    style="display: none;">

<button type="button"
    ng-click="clickUpload()">Upload</button>



$scope.clickUpload = function(){
    angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
};
```

Comment: What's wring with jquery?

Comment: Angular includes jquery lite.  If you drop in jquery it uses that instead. I see nothing wrong with using something as intended.

Comment: I agree with @Gepsens, the questions asks how to trigger the event "with angularjs".  Unless you drop in the full jquery this solution doesn't work.

Comment: sure it does. `angular.element.click()` for the jqlite click event or `angular.element.get(0).click()` for the native one.

Comment: @chovy jqLite has neither click() nor get().

Comment: i use jquery. drops right in. jqLite is pretty limited I guess. I wasn't sure how limited.

Comment: I agree with @Gepsens too... no use at all for pure angular.

Comment: Nowadays Angular uses the triggerHandler function on angular.element

Comment: It may not be the most elegant or Angular-only solution, but it's a practical solution that works for 99% of people.

Comment: 100% of people who've included jQuery. 0% of people who have not.

Comment: This does NOT work for me as I receive "$apply is already in progress"  error for some reason.

Comment: As Angular best practices, you shouldn't do DOM manipulation (or querying for this matter) inside your controllers

Comment: I ended up with ```el.srcElement.previousElementSibling.click();```

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and this fiddle is the shizzle :) It uses a directive to properly style the file field and you can even make it an image or whatever.

http://jsfiddle.net/stereosteve/v5Rdc/7/

```js
/*globals angular:true*/
var buttonApp = angular.module('buttonApp', [])

buttonApp.directive('fileButton', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

      var el = angular.element(element)
      var button = el.children()[0]

      el.css({
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: button.offsetWidth,
        height: button.offsetHeight
      })

      var fileInput = angular.element('<input type="file" multiple />')
      fileInput.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        'z-index': '2',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        opacity: '0',
        cursor: 'pointer'
      })

      el.append(fileInput)


    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div ng-app="buttonApp">

  <div file-button>
    <button class='btn btn-success btn-large'>Select your awesome file</button>
  </div>

  <div file-button>
    <img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This answer fits the spirit of angular js. Should be the accepted answer. I'm however still search on github for a offical project with such a directive.

Comment: Triggering a click on the file input has proved impossible, so this method of overlaying a transparent file input in order to capture the click is the only working solution I've found.

Comment: @Osiloke I would like to add a directive to the input.  Considering $compile, how should I compile and append?

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting $scope binding errors make sure you wrap the click event code on a setTimeout Function.

**VIEW**

```
<input id="upload"
    type="file"
    ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"
    style="display: none;">

<button type="button"
    ng-click="clickUpload()">Upload</button>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.clickUpload = function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
      angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: any reason not to use `$timeout` ?

Answer (score 2):

for jqLite just use triggerHandler with event name, To simulate a "click" try:

```js
angular.element("tr").triggerHandler("click");
```

[Here's the list of jQLite commands](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Even this code snippet produces same error.

Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! 
See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/jqLite/nosel

Answer (score 1):

Simply have them in the same controller, and do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="upload"
    type="file"
    ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"
    style="display: none;">

<button type="button"
    ng-click="startUpload()">Upload</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.files = [];
  $scope.startUpload = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
      $upload($scope.files[i]);
    } 
  }
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
     $scope.files = $files;
  };
}];
```

This is, in my opinion, the best way to do it in angular. Using jQuery to find the element and trigger an event isn't the best practice.

Comment: Your missing the point, the `<input type=file>` button is hidden because its a PITA to style properly across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem and have written a solution for those of you who are using Angular. You can write a custom directive composed of a container, a button, and an input element with type file. With CSS you then place the input over the custom button but with opacity 0. You set the containers height and width to exactly the offset width and height of the button and the input's height and width to 100% of the container.

the directive

```
angular.module('myCoolApp')
  .directive('fileButton', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'components/directives/fileButton/fileButton.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        var container = angular.element('.file-upload-container');
        var button = angular.element('.file-upload-button');

        container.css({
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: button.offsetWidth,
            height: button.offsetHeight
        })

      }

    };
  });
```

a jade template if you are using jade

```
div(class="file-upload-container") 
    button(class="file-upload-button") +
    input#file-upload(class="file-upload-input", type='file', onchange="doSomethingWhenFileIsSelected()")
```

the same template in html if you are using html

```
<div class="file-upload-container">
   <button class="file-upload-button"></button>
   <input class="file-upload-input" id="file-upload" type="file" onchange="doSomethingWhenFileIsSelected()" /> 
</div>
```

the css

```
.file-upload-button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 66px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 228, 0); 
    color: rgb(255, 228, 0);
}
.file-upload-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as pointed out by other answers, is to use

```
angular.element(element).trigger(event);
```

Here's an example of how I randomly select multiple `select` elements:

```
$scope.randomize = function(){
    var games = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.games select'));

    games.forEach(function(e){
        // Logically change the element (Angular won't know about this)
        e.selectedIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10) < 50 ? 1 : 2;

        // Manually tell Angular that the DOM has changed
        angular.element(e).trigger('change');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer posted by Osiloke (Which was the easiest and most complete imho) and I added a change event listener. Works great! Thanks Osiloke. See below if you are interested:

HTML:

```
  <div file-button>
        <button class='btn btn-success btn-large'>Select your awesome file</button>
   </div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('fileButton', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

      var el = angular.element(element)
      var button = el.children()[0]

      el.css({
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: button.offsetWidth,
        height: button.offsetHeight
      })

      var fileInput = angular.element('<input id='+scope.file_button_id+' type="file" multiple />')
      fileInput.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        'z-index': '2',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        opacity: '0',
        cursor: 'pointer'
      })

      el.append(fileInput)
      document.getElementById(scope.file_button_id).addEventListener('change', scope.file_button_open, false); 
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.file_button_id = "wo_files";    
$scope.file_button_open = function() 
{
  alert("Files are ready!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more directive

**html**

```
<btn-file-selector/>
```

**code**

```
.directive('btnFileSelector',[function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE', 
    template: '<div></div>', 
    link: function(s,e,a){

      var el = angular.element(e);
      var button = angular.element('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-upload">Add File</button>'); 
      var fileForm = angular.element('<input type="file" style="display:none;"/>'); 

      fileForm.on('change', function(){
         // Actions after the file is selected
         console.log( fileForm[0].files[0].name );
      });

      button.bind('click',function(){
        fileForm.click();
      });     


     el.append(fileForm);
     el.append(button);
    }
  }  
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

best and simple way to use native java Script which is one liner code.

`document.querySelector('#id').click();`

Just add 'id' to your html element like

`<button id="myId1" ng-click="someFunction()"></button>`

check condition in javascript code

`if(condition) {
   document.querySelector('#myId1').click();
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="file" #imageFile />

<button (click)="imageFile.click()"></button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30221598)

Comment: The answer caters to an Angular implementation. The question was around AngularJS.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are over complicated things a bit. Do you really need to trigger a click on the input from your button ?

I suggest you just apply a proper style to your input and the ngFileSelect directive will do the rest and call your onFileSelect function whenever a file is submitted :

```
input.file {
    cursor: pointer;
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-300px, 0px) scale(4);
}
```

Comment: styling input file buttons is not a good solution, since they very completely between browsers. Its much easier (and is common practice) to just hide the ugly beast and trigger its click event programmatically instead.