# Trigger click sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange problem with my `AngularJS` project. I have 2 `buttons` that trigger `inputs` below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="triggerInput('B1')">B1</button>
<input id="b1Input" type="file" accept="image/*" class="hide" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().changeImage(this)" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="triggerInput('B2')">B2</button>
<input id="b2Input" type="file" accept="image/*" class="hide" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().changeImage(this)" />
```

I tried to debug the `JS` code, but it seems to be okay. Unfortunatelly, Sometimes I have to click chosen button couple times (2-4) to make the input open. Maybe the `jQuery` selector is bad?

Here's the code:

```
$scope.triggerInput = function (type) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var selector = "";
        switch (type) {
            case "B1":
                selector = "b1Input";
                break;
            case "B2":
                selector = "b2Input";
                break;
        }

        $("input[id='" + selector + "']").trigger("click");
    });
};
```

Comment: create a directive put your dom related logic there instead of doing what you are doing ..

Comment: Will it change anything? I think this solution should work as well

Comment: may be or may be not .. sometime `angular.element(this).scope()` need timeout to execute.

Comment: Hmm, that's why I added $timeout in triggerInput

Comment: that input won't effect onclick's `angular.element(this).scope().changeImage(this)` this portion also need timeout to call `changeImage`

Comment: Ok, but changeImage is triggered after I chose an image. I have problems with openning a dialog when I can select my images.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use this line(which is below) into controller. I think you can write a [directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628410/how-can-i-trigger-the-click-event-of-another-element-in-ng-click-using-angularjs) to populate this.

```
$("input[id='" + selector + "']").trigger("click");
```

Correct your code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="triggerInput('B2',$event)">B2</button>


$scope.triggerInput = function (type,e) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var selector = "";
        switch (type) {
            case "B1":
                selector = "b1Input";
                break;
            case "B2":
                selector = "b2Input";
                break;
        }

       angular.element(e.target).siblings('#'+selector).trigger('click');
       //or simply write this
       //$("#"+selector).trigger("click");
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Could you explain why I shouldn't use this line `$("input[id='" + selector + "']").trigger("click");`? How this differs from `$("#"+selector).trigger("click");`?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I can't understand why